# Cannot find YAML module

Tags: python, pip, yaml

I am currently trying to use my YAML file but I get an error when trying to run my programme when it reaches 'import yaml' line.

The error is shown below

```
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

Even though I was able to successfully install it

```
Collecting pyyaml
Installing collected packages: pyyaml
Successfully installed pyyaml-3.13
```

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Please expand your question to include [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: could you try `pip install pyyaml` once and try running the code ?

Comment: Ensure you installed `pyyaml` for the python interpreter you execute your code with

Answer (score 0):

```
which python
```

> /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python

```
which pip
```

> /home/user/anaconda3/bin/pip

These must match. Than you can run `pip install PyYAML`

---

For such problems I can recommend conda. Using conda all dependencies are matched.

Here is a description how to use [environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) with conda.

The good thing about this approach is that you can change the version of your software (e.g. python) at any time, not affecting your other projects.

Moreover you can use pip in it just as before.